# How to schedule a process in a router

Tags: networking, tcl, expect, router, cisco-ios

I am using the below code to execute a TCL script inside a cisco router.

```
Router#tclsh
Router(tcl)#source tftp://tftp-server/tcl-script.tcl
```

Everyday I wanted to execute same script in my router at 10 PM. how can I schedule it?

Regards,

Varghese

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a Cisco IOS script to run a set of commands at a certain time each day?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21454227/how-to-write-a-cisco-ios-script-to-run-a-set-of-commands-at-a-certain-time-each)

Answer (score 2):

You need look at `kron` command. See [Cisco command reference](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/cns/configuration/15-mt/cns-15-mt-book/cns-cmd-sched.html).
And write something like this:

```
configure terminal
    kron policy-list policy-day10pm
        cli tclsh tftp://tftp-server/tcl-script.tcl 
        exit
    kron occurrence day10pm at 22:00 recurring
        policy-list policy-day10pm
        exit
    exit
show kron schedule
>> policy-day10pm inactive, will run again in 0 days 08:05:41 at 22:00 on
```